# Using os.system in a for-loop not responding

Tags: python, os.system

I'm trying to call a script multple times by enumerating through a list of arguments using the following loop and os.system:

```
    for tcp_obj in data[0]:
        print("checking" + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
        os.system("isthisipbad.py --ip " + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything when it reaches this loop. It doesn't throw any errors at all. It won't even print the 'checking' line I inserted. Is my implementation not acceptable somehow? This works fine when it's simply a single line such as:

```
    os.system("isthisipbad.py --ip " + RemoteIpAddress)
```

The entire function is as follows:

```
def render_text(self, outfd, data):
    self.table_header(outfd,
                      [(self.offset_column(), "[addrpad]"),
                       ("Local Address", "25"),
                       ("Remote Address", "25"),
                       ("Pid", "")
                       ])

    for tcp_obj in data[0]:
        local = "{0}:{1}".format(tcp_obj.LocalIpAddress, tcp_obj.LocalPort)
        remote = "{0}:{1}".format(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress, tcp_obj.RemotePort)
        self.table_row(outfd,
                        tcp_obj.obj_offset,
                        local, remote,
                        tcp_obj.Pid)

    outfd.write("\n")
    self.table_header(outfd,[("Processid", "20")])     
    for tcp_obj in data[1]:
        self.table_row(outfd,tcp_obj.ImageFileName)

    for tcp_obj in data[0]:
        print("checking" + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
        os.system("isthisipbad.py --ip " + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
```

It is called before to create a table based on the information in data[0] in the first for-loop, and that works fine.

It should be noted that 'data' is what is returned at the end of the calculate function.

Comment: Depends what's in `data[0]`.

Comment: It is called once before in the first for-loop, and in that loop, it pulls from data[0] as needed.

Comment: Depends what's in `data[0]`.

Comment: Why are you using an OS call to a Python script from Python? Import the script - call its function

Comment: @cricket, mostly for testing purposes but I now realize my complication. What is the easiest way to pass the arguments when calling its main?

Comment: Are you sure it's getting to that second `data[0]` loop, and not getting stuck somewhere earlier?  If you comment out the `os.system` call and just do `print('foo')`, does that execute?

Comment: If that other script is just a main function (or has no function), you'll need to make one that accepts the ip as a parameter

Comment: You are using for loops that will not loop. Everywhere you have a "for tcp_obj in data[0]:", just replace it with tcp_obj = data[0]. Unless data is a list of lists, you are not looping. Same for data[1].

Answer (score -1):

Change data[0] to just data.

Yours:

```
 for tcp_obj in data[0]:
        print("checking" + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
        os.system("isthisipbad.py --ip " + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
```

Changed:

```
 for tcp_obj in data:
        print("checking" + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
        os.system("isthisipbad.py --ip " + str(tcp_obj.RemoteIpAddress))
```

Comment: This will not work. data is comprised of a list that is returned at the end of the calculate function